# Sort values in a column with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark data frame within my Jupyter notebook. I want to sort specific values in the column "Keywords". I only need to return those rows that have one or a few matching values.

Here is how my column that needs to be sorted looks like.

```
+--------------------+
|            Keywords|
+--------------------+
|      ["apocalypse"]|
|["nuclear","physi...|
|                null|
|["childhood","imm...|
|["canned tomatoes...|
|                null|
|["american","beef...|
|["runway","ethose...|
|["taylor swift st...|
|["beauty","colleg...|
|                null|
|["curly hair|coil...|
|["glossier|shoppi...|
|["stacey abrams",...|
|["quentin taranti...|
|                null|
|["Mexican|Cinco D...|
|["Bridal Spring 2...|
|                null|
|["everyday athlet...|
+--------------------+
```

I want to create a new dataframe that has the rows only if Keywords = "beauty", "runway". How would I go about it? I was going to create a for loop with Python but not sure how to make it within Spark dataframe... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you include the expected output and your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a generic solution, you can use a list to specify the words/keywords that you want to include as part of your output and use it in the filter of the `df`.

Code looks like:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType

valid_words = {"beauty", "runway"} # Define a list of valid words
filtered_df = df.filter(udf(lambda kwords: len(valid_words & set(kwords))>0, # Condition to identify if we have at least, 1 valid word
                                  BooleanType())(df.Keywords))
filtered_df.show()
```

So that, if you need to include any other valid word, you only update the list (`valid_words`).

Additionally, title should be updated, this is not regarding sort, is more about filtering rows given an ArrayType column.

Comment: Can I get context/reason about the downvote?

Comment: Hey, I have not downvoted! Your answers have been super helpful! It must be a mistake.

Comment: Also, I have tried your code, which gave me a long error, but basically TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable. Which means I have to drop NaN values. I had about 4M NaN values so I did this: ```spark = spark_renamed.filter(spark_renamed.Keywords.isNotNull())
# Define a list of valid words
valid_words = {"beauty", "runway"} 

# Condition to identify if we have at least, 1 valid word
filtered_df = spark.filter(udf(lambda kwords: len(valid_words & set(kwords))>0, 
                                  BooleanType())(spark.Keywords))
filtered_df.show()``` Gave me 0 results

Comment: I think it has something to do with the format of my rows. Some of them are ```["friendsgiving","thanksgiving","dessert","condiment","oat","cinnamon"]``` and some are like this ```["google|microsoft|stadia|XBox|xcloud"]```

Comment: You should avoid use `spark` for a `dataframe` or any other object reference. Regarding the issue about the format, I would recommend to have a previous step to clean your data first then apply your filter over the formatted data. For example, If you already identified 2 different formats on the values, you can use a `map` and check if you have a single string with (`contains`) at least one pipe (`|`) and  convert it to an array. So that, after the map you will work only with valid arrays.

Comment: But it was impossible for me to convert Spark df to any other format due to the volume of the data. Now after cleaning the data, I have 7M rows to work with. And it still didn't convert toPandas. Out of curiosity, why should I avoid to work with Spark df? And what are the alternatives?

Comment: I meant, to name your `df` different than `spark`, instead of `spark = spark_renamed.filter(spark_renamed.Keywords.isNotNull())` use some other name like `spark_renamed = spark_renamed.filter(spark_renamed.Keywords.isNotNull())`.

Comment: Ah! Gotcha! Already did. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Cesar, I was hoping you can help me with smth else. Your code worked perfectly fine for me in the past for one dataframe. I am working on another one at the moment. Somehow the exact same code returns an empty dataframe. My raw data in column looks like this (for the first three rows) : ```[\mashed potatoes\"
[\american\"
[\runway\"```

Comment: I think that could be caused by special characters on the DF data. Before to apply any filter and if you are not completely sure about if the data is cleaned, I would recommend to add a previous clean up step, where you can remove spaces with `trim` or special characters with some regex.

Comment: Do you offer tutoring by any chance?

Comment: Sure, drop me an email. You can find it on my profile.

Answer (score 2):

`Since the expected output is difficult to define, this can be used for what I have understood so far.`

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([[["apocalypse"]],[[None]],[["beauty","test"]],[["runway","beauty"]]]).toDF("testcol")
df.show()
+----------------+
|         testcol|
+----------------+
|    [apocalypse]|
|              []|
|  [beauty, test]|
|[runway, beauty]|
+----------------+


df.filter(F.array_contains(F.col("testcol"),"beauty")|F.array_contains(F.col("testcol"),"runway")).show()
+----------------+
|         testcol|
+----------------+
|  [beauty, test]|
|[runway, beauty]|
+----------------+
```